# H2 performance degrade using remote tcp server

Tags: database, performance, h2

I have a simple application that uses a single connection, the flow is something like this:

```
SELECT QUERY 
CONNECTION CLOSE

for(..) //thousands of iterations
{
  SIMPLE SELECT QUERY
}
BUSINESS LOGIC
CONNECTION CLOSE

for(..) //thousands of iterations
{
  SIMPLE SELECT QUERY
}
BUSINESS LOGIC
CONNECTION CLOSE
```

When i use the embedded connection mode, the application ends in about 20 seconds, but when i switch to the server mode, the performances deteriorate:

- localhost: 110 seconds
- remote server (LAN): more than 30 minutes

Each query retrieves a **small amount of data**.

Is there an explanation for such a poor performance? How can i speed up the application without rewriting the code?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you single record selects inside the loops? Try to: select multiple records in one query, use prepared statements.

Comment: @SubOptimal the query is very fast, otherwise i would have bad performance even using the embedded mode

Comment: After a lot of tries, i found a way to speed up the application tuning the parameter CACHE_SIZE. I got a 20% improvement

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem in a local network. Could you please let me know which H2 version are you using, which size your database has (the *.h2.db file) how many records are in the tables you are fetching from, what are your H2 database settings (if not using the defaults). Because if this is a reproducible problem it would be worth to open a bug ticket.

Comment: Database version: **1.3.168**
Database settings: **LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000; AUTO_RECONNECT=true;**
Database size: **270MB**
Record count: **8000**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did following test with your provided H2 version.

1. create a test database with 500.000 records, database size 990 MB
   `java -cp h2-1.3.168.jar;. PerfH2 create`
2. select random 8.000 records on the indexed column
   in embedded mode -> 1.7 sec
   `java -cp h2-1.3.168.jar;. PerfH2 embedded`
   in server (localhost) mode -> 2.6 sec
   `java -cp h2-1.3.168.jar;. PerfH2 server`

If you face the problem already using server mode as `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/your_database`, then something with your environment or the way you access the server mode seems to be wrong. Try with a stripped done application and check if the problem still exists. If you have can reproduce the problem also with a stripped down version please post the code.

Find the code used for the test below.

```
public class PerfH2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        if (null == args[0]) {
                showUsage();
                return;
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        switch (args[0]) {
            case "create":
                createDatabase();
                break;
            case "embedded":
                try (Connection conn = getEmbeddedConnection()) {
                    execSelects(conn);
                }
                break;
            case "server":
                try (Connection conn = getServerConnection()) {
                    execSelects(conn);
                }
                break;
            default:
                showUsage();
        }
        System.out.printf("duration: %d%n", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }

    private static Connection getServerConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/perf_test", "sa", "");
    }

    private static Connection getEmbeddedConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:d:/temp/perf_test", "sa", "");
    }

    private static void execSelects(final Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        Random rand = new Random(1);
        String selectSql = "SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE ID = ?";
        PreparedStatement selectStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSql);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
            selectStatement.setInt(1, rand.nextInt(500_000));
            ResultSet rs = selectStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("retrieved rows: %d%n", count);
    }

    private static void createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:d:/temp/perf_test", "sa", "")) {
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(1024))";
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTable);

            String insertSql = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement insertStmnt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1024 / 10; i++) {
                sb.append("[cafebabe]");
            }

            String value = sb.toString();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                insertStmnt.setInt(1, i);
                insertStmnt.setString(2, value);
                count += insertStmnt.executeUpdate();
            }
            System.out.printf("inserted rows: %d%n", count);
            conn.commit();

            String createIndex = "CREATE INDEX TEST_INDEX ON TEST_TABLE(ID)";
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createIndex);
        }
    }

    private static void showUsage() {
        System.out.println("usage: PerfH2 [create|embedded|server]");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. How do you selected the 8.000 records? With a single query or with 8.000 queries?

Comment: @vincenzoiafelice I added the code I used to the test. I did 8.000 single queries.

Answer (score 2):

compare your problem like accessing a cup of coffee.

If you access your coffe on your table/workdesk it is comparable like a in memory access to your database (H2 embedded)
It takes about seconds (coffee) and microseconds (h2 embedded)

if you need to go to the kitchen to access a cup of coffe it will take you the travel time from your chair to the kitchen + back (response).
The kitchen is comparable like TCP accessing or file accessing your local database.
It takes you minutes (coffee) and one digit milliseconds (h2 tcp localhost or local file)

if you need to go to a coffeshop outside to access a cup of coffee it will take you at least 15 mins to get a cup of coffee (and ages ( at least 2 digits milliseconds) in h2 tcp on remote machine)

now the question, how many times do you want to travel to a coffeshop?
If I give you a iteration (for loop) over 1000 times to the coffeshop, would you just asking me after the second or the third time if I am kidding? Why do you bother a IO dependent system on long travel times over the network?

So in your case, if you reduce your second for-loop into one SQL query, you will get a great performance locally and of course especially on the remote way.

I hope I could explain you the situation with the coffee, since it explains the problem better.

So to answer the last question, you have to rewrite your "thousands of iterations" for-loops.

**Update 1**

Forgot, if your for-loops are writing loops (update/insert) you can use batch queries. How to use them depends on your language you are using. Batches are to provide the database a bunch (e.g. multiple hundreds) of insert/updates before the operation takes in place on the database.

Comment: As i said, i know that the code can be improved, but i can't rewrite it. I agree that with the server mode the performances became worse, but in my case they are very bad. I can't believe that using localhost i get an order of magnitude bigger.

Comment: Just to sum up, the question is: "why the performance is **so** bad?"

Comment: vincenzo, how many interations are you doing? And what are the SQLs?

Comment: For the above example, each loop has about 8.000 iterations. The query selects few columns from a couple of tables joined using an index. I have verified the execution plan, the query is very very fast.

Comment: Vincenco, so you are fireing 16000 queries to the database. So in median every statement takes about 115ms, which is not very fast. But if you get it down to lets say some good 30ms => it is still 8 minutes for the 16000 iterations.

Comment: So the only way is to modify the code. Either by changing it directly or by doing some AOP tricks. The only way to provide the database some optimizations options is to either do batch queries http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcStatement.html (#addBatch) or by chaning the loop. For example you could create a around Aspect around the method with AOP and execute an optimized code and just skip the existing method with the really stupid mass iteration via IO resource.

Comment: the main issue seems to be the communication protocol. I think it's not very performing, otherwise i would have bad performance even using the embedded mode

Comment: I have checked the network, it works fine. The issue occurs even using localhost...